# How to traverse JSON model?

Tags: sapui5

**Image**

[image]

**Controller.js**

```js
item: function(evt) {
    var list = sap.ui.getCore().byId('appListId');
    var sItem = list.getSelectedItem();

    var oBindingContext = sItem.getBindingContext('products');
    var sPath = oBindingContext.sPath;

    console.log(sPath);  // get path /collection/0/App/0

    var context = sap.ui.getCore().byId("appListId").getModel('products')
    .getContext(sPath);

    var start = sPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    var appIndex = sPath.substring(start, sPath.length);

    this.router.navTo("selectedAppRecord", {
        catIndex : this.subCatIndex,
        appIndex : appIndex
    });
}
```

**Path of JSON Array :**

```js
get this path /collection/0/App/0
```

**I have an JSON array :**

```js
{
    "collection": [{
        "model": "08 Report Fraud",
        "App": [{
            "App": "COUNCIL001",
            "description": "Benefit Fraud",
            "module": "08 Report Fraud",
            "iConClass": "icon-devil",
            "UserSpecific": "Yes"
        }]
    }]
}
```

finally my goal is how to get this UserSpecific key in control side.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Could you please add some more details describing your problem?

Comment: @hirse I got the path as above function, and by using the path want to Key of UserSpecific which is in JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getProperty` function of the BindingContext to get relative properties.

```js
var oItem = sap.ui.getCore().byId('appListId').getSelectedItem();
oItem.getBindingContext('products').getProperty('UserSpecific');
```

---

In your handler function I would recommend to get the current item from the event:

```js
oEvent.getSource() || oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem()
```

Depending on the type of event (ListItem#select or List#selectionChange).